# Returning correct array

Tags: java, arrays, path

I am trying to make #java code what will find path from [0][0] to [k-1][m-1]. But my created code is not working rightly.

End of program should be printed `(0,0) (0,1) (1,1)` but I got `(-1,-1)` what means that it can't find path. I think, problem is with returning array. But how to fix that?

My code:
If a particular labyrinth[i][j] == 1, it means that there is a wall in this path and there is no way out. Otherwise are checked right/left/up/down or these exist and are not visited if it executes then a path from that cell is sought. If several paths are found then the shortest one is returned.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[][] visited = new int[2][2];
        int[][] input = {{0,0},{1,0}};
        int[][] result = dfs(input, 2, 2, 0, 0, new int[2][2], visited); 
        for(int x =0; x<result.length; x++){
            System.out.print("(" + result[x][0] + "," + result[x][1] + ") ");
        }
    }
    public static boolean validMove(int k, int m, int i, int j, int[][] visited){
        try{
            if(i>=0 && j>=0 && i<=(k-1) && j<=(m-1)){
                if(visited[i][j] != 1) return true;
            }
            return false;
        }catch (Exception e) {return false;}
        //return true;
    }
    public static int[][] dfs(int[][] maze, int k, int m, int j, int i, int[][] path, int[][] visited){
        visited[i][j] = (int)1;
        int[][] er = {{-1,-1}};
        if(i == (k-1) && j == (m-1)){
            int[][] resultThis = new int[path.length+1][2];
            for(int x =0; x<path.length; x++){
                resultThis[x][0] = path[x][0];
                resultThis[x][1] = path[x][1];
            }
            resultThis[resultThis.length-1] = new int[]{i,j};
            return resultThis;
        }
        if(maze[i][j] == 1) return new int[][]{{-1,-1}};
        else{
            boolean bl1 = false;
            boolean bl2 = false;
            boolean bl3 = false;
            boolean bl4 = false;
            int[][] blok1 = null;
            int[][] blok2 = null;
            int[][] blok3 = null;
            int[][] blok4 = null;
            if(validMove(k, m, i+1, j, visited)){
                int[][] option = new int[path.length+1][2];
                for(int x =0; x<path.length; x++){
                    option[x][0] = path[x][0];
                    option[x][1] = path[x][1];
                }
                option[option.length-1] = new int[]{i,j};
                blok1 = dfs(maze, k, m, j, i+1, option, visited);               
                if(!(blok1.length == er.length) || (blok1[0][0] == -1)){bl1 = true;}
            }
            if(validMove(k, m, i, j+1, visited)){
                int[][] option = new int[path.length+1][2];
                for(int x =0; x<path.length; x++){
                    option[x][0] = path[x][0];
                    option[x][1] = path[x][1];
                }
                option[option.length-1] = new int[]{i,j};
                blok2 = dfs(maze, k, m, j, i+1, option, visited);  
                if(!(blok2.length == er.length && blok2[0][0] == -1)){bl2 = true;}
            }
            if(validMove(k, m, i-1, j, visited)){
                int[][] option = new int[path.length+1][2];
                for(int x =0; x<path.length; x++){
                    option[x][0] = path[x][0];
                    option[x][1] = path[x][1];
                }
                option[option.length-1] = new int[]{i,j};
                blok3 = dfs(maze, k, m, j, i+1, option, visited);  
                if(!(blok3.length == er.length && blok3[0][0] == -1)){bl3 = true;}
            }
            if(validMove(k, m, i, j-1, visited)){
                int[][] option = new int[path.length+1][2];
                for(int x =0; x<path.length; x++){
                    option[x][0] = path[x][0];
                    option[x][1] = path[x][1];
                }
                option[option.length-1] = new int[]{i,j};
                blok4 = dfs(maze, k, m, j, i+1, option, visited);  
                if(!(blok4.length == er.length && blok4[0][0] == -1)){bl4 = true;}
            }
            if(!(bl1 && bl2 && bl3 && bl4))return er;
            int count = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            if(bl1 && (blok1.length < count)){
                count = blok1.length;
                path = blok1;
            }
            if(bl2 && (blok2.length < count)){
                count = blok2.length;
                path = blok2;
            }
            if(bl3 && (blok3.length < count)){
                count = blok3.length;
                path = blok3;
            }
            if(bl4 && (blok4.length < count)){
                count = blok4.length;
                path = blok4;
            }
            
            return path;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the intention with this line: `visited[i][j] = (int)1;`?
I am confused that this is allowed.

Comment: @Nico why shouldn't it be allowed? This is just setting the value `1` at position `(i,j)` of the array. The explicit cast is useless, but allowed nonetheless.

Comment: @QBrute my bad. I got confused by that line. It's perfectly fine.